# where is the correct and recent ehcache maven repository

Tags: maven-2, ehcache, sonatype

I've been struggling to get *ehcache* 2.1.0 in my environment. Anytime I thought I got it right, it's just not downloading it. Here is where I set the repository:

```
 <repository>
 <!--<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>-->
     <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/sourceforge-releases</url>
     <id>sonatype-mirror</id>
     <layout>default</layout>
     <name>Repository for library including ehcache recent ones</name>
 </repository>
```

And I add the dependency this way :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there anything that's i'm doing wrong or not properly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ehcache is available in the maven central repository, there is no need to add a particular repository.

However, the `ehcache` artifact is *special*, it's an "aggregating" artifact which is of type **`pom`**. So the dependency should be declared like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Of course, you can also declare dependencies on individual modules if you want (e.g. `ehcache-core`) in which case you don't need to specify the type.

#### References

- Ehcache Documentation

  - [Java Requirements and Dependencies](http://ehcache.org/documentation/dependencies.html)

Comment: There is a JAR, not a POM only, for `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.8.1`

Answer (score 10):

`net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.1.0` is a dependency of type `pom` therefore you need to specify it:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId> 
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId> 
  <version>2.1.0</version> 
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

**See also:**

- [3.6. POM Best Practices](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)